# Javascript array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using an array to store a number of other arrays and separating each stored array by adding 'fin' at the end.

What's really throwing me is this; when I display what javascript thinks is the length of this array, it says that the array has 603 elements, whereas in reality the array contains approximately 90 elements. :-(

Code as requested:-

```
//  Declare the array

var arrForAllData = new Array();

//  Concatenate all the arrays to build the 'arrForAllData' array

arrForAllData = arrApplicationData + ",fin," + arrCmdbIds + ",fin," + arrBaAvail + ",fin," + arrAppStatus + ",fin," + arrMaxAchieve + ",fin," + arrBreaches + ",fin," + arrMTTR + ",fin," + arrMTBF + ",fin," + arrMTBSI + ",fin," + arrCleanDays + ",fin," + arrHistBaAvail + ",fin," + arrHistBreaches + ",fin," + arrHistDuration;
```

I'm using 'fin' as the delimiter for each array as I have to rebuild the arrays later to save on having to do API calls to re-create most of the data.

```
// Example array

arrApplicationData contains

Downstream,CIM,Eserve,FPS,Global,GSAP

// Display the data in the arrForAllData

alert("arrForAllData contains " + arrForAllData );
```

This alert displays all the elements in the array as I expect, all comma separated.

```
// Calculate the length of the array

var adlen = arrForAllData.length;

alert("Number of elements in arrForAllData is " + adlen );
```

This alert displays 'adlen' as 603, which, as I say below is the count of all the individual characters.

For some reason the 'array.length' is counting each individual character.

Has anyone come across this before and if you have, is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code.

Comment: How exactly did you store the other arrays?

Comment: What you did is `string.length` and you will get individual characters. But without code, I cannot point you to the right direction.

Comment: "separating each stored array by adding 'fin'" Have you ever heard of [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: Definitely, you are not using _arrays_ as you think. And this _fin_ is really weird.

Comment: I assume that You don't know how to create an array in javascript... so read this
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: @steveg, post your code or they will close your question

Comment: As I'm a new memeber I can't post images, if could add some images, it will be easier to explain

Comment: @steveg, NO, we don't need any images - just the source code for what you call _array_

Comment: @Givi - w3schools? nooooo! Here's a decent reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @steveg, what is your problem? Click http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17567602/edit and add your "_array_" definition to your question. It doesn't hurt to write your code like `var myArray = ['something', 'something-else']; alert(myArray.length);`

Comment: ElmoVanKielmo - my problem is the returned value of 603 from array.length, I expect array.length to give me a figure of around 90

Comment: @steveg, you made a _string_ of your _arrays_ - that's the problem. I've flagged this question to enable answering again - once it's unlocked I'll post a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Try this instead `var arrForAllData = []; arrForAllData.push(arrApplicationData); arrForAllData.push(arrCmdbIds );` etc.  Please forget about this crazy 'fin' idea! (and read about arrays in the link I posted)

Comment: Thanks UpTheCreek, I'll give that a go. Cheers :-) P.S. I have the link open that you suggested, thanks again. :-)

Comment: @UpTheCreek, +1 for you. I'm waitng for unblocking this question to post the code with proper formatting instead of tapeworm in a comment :)

Comment: @Givi http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I'm curious about why you thought that would work? Do you have experience with another language that allows array expansion with + or did you assume it would work? I'm curious from a language friendliness point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't concatenate arrays with strings as they are casted to string. Here's what you need:

```
var arrForAllData = new Array(
     arrApplicationData,
     arrCmdbIds,
     arrBaAvail,
     arrAppStatus,
     arrMaxAchieve,
     arrBreaches,
     arrMTTR,
     arrMTBF,
     arrMTBSI,
     arrCleanDays,
     arrHistBaAvail,
     arrHistBreaches
);

// And now for existing array you can always add new item
arrForAllData.push(arrHistDuration);

// You access elements of array by their index
var a = arrForAllData[5];
// 'a' is now holding the 'arrBreaches' as arrays are indexed from 0

// You can iterate over array, for example to count all the items inside nested arrays
var all_items_amount = 0;
for(var i=0; i<arrForAllData.length; i++){
    all_items_amount += arrForAllData[i].length;
}
alert(arrForAllData.length); // This will alert the length of main array
alert(all_items_amount); // This will alert the number of elements in all nested arrays
```

As an alternative to the array definition used, arrays may be instantiated by:

```
var x = []; // Empty array
var x = new Array(); // Empty array too
var x = [a, b, c];  // Array with three items made of variables 'a', 'b' and 'c'
var x = new Array(new object(), 'xxx', [], a);  // Array with four items:
// new instance of object, string 'xxx', new empty array and variable 'a'
```

Comment: Your last example has four items :)

Comment: Hi ElmoVanKielmo - thanks for the code and thanks for taking the time to help me out.